# Make node.js to run on startup on unbuntu 14.4

Tags: node.js, web, ubuntu-14.04

I want to deploy a nodejs webapp .
And the nodejs server should be started on boot.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pm2 startup script for the same. Please refer the docs on below link
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Answer (score 0):

You can put your executable command for your nodejs server in `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your command in .bash_profile

it will execute when you login

Comment: sometimes the file is named .profile